# How to post a login form from another page to /login?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, post, authentication

I just started using Laravel and followed the first set of tutorials.

How do I post a login / registration form from another page to the `/login` page? It redirects me back to the page I submitted the form from.

I am using the following code:

```
<form method="POST" role="form" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <!-- fields here (email, password) -->
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your form, placed anywhere on your site, will post to /login. the logic in the auth controller sends the user back to the page s/he came from